# How can I load images from the hard disk and display them in pictureBox with timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string image in filesRadar)
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(image);
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string image in filesSatellite)
            {
                pictureBox2.Load(image);
            }
        }
```

I'm not getting any errors/exceptions and using breakpoint it stop on the Load line/s but it's not showing the images on any of the pictureBoxes.

Comment: Your loops are going to try to display *ALL* the images one after the other as fast as possible which is probably not what you want.  Otherwise, check that the files collections store the correct, full path for the files

Answer (score 1):

This is working. could be in other ways but it's working.

```
        int radImagesCount = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radImagesCount++;

            if (radImagesCount == filesRadar.Length)
            {
                radImagesCount = 0;
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filesRadar[radImagesCount]);
        }

        int satImagesCount = 0;
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            satImagesCount++;

            if (satImagesCount == filesSatellite.Length)
            {
                satImagesCount = 0;
            }

            pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(filesSatellite[satImagesCount]);
        }
```

Both filesRadar and filesSatellite are string[] arrays contains the images fils.